# Publish enterprise app as a contractor, which certificates and provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

As a contractor I am working for a company and my job is to build an iOS app and publish it for enterprise distribution. Now the problem is that the company which employed me is kind of sitting on their certificates. Here is what they gave me:

- An enterprise distribution provisioning profile
- An enterprise distribution certificate (no private key)

I think this is not enough to publish the app for enterprise distribution. What else will I need?

The problem is they are very uncooperative (it is a big company and my guess is the IT department is not happy that the job was given to an outsider), I do not even have a direct contact to them.

Comment: You can't build the app without private key of certificate in my opinion.

Comment: Without private key, you cannot use the distribution certificate to compile & publish applications.

Comment: What would be the regular workflow here? Would it be normal to get the private key from the company?

Answer (score 1):

1) If they want you to build the app, they have to give you the private key for the distribution certificate.
2) Another option would be that you check in the code in their repository (what you're probably doing anyway) and they build and upload the app themselves.
3) Or they give you access to a machine running Xcode with the proper certificates and keys already installed.

If they are concerned about the security of the certificate, 2) would probably be the best option for them.